# Magento 2 Composer install error

Tags: magento2.3, composer, php-7, composer-update

[image]

The following are causeing PHP version error
plz suggest solution

Comment: composer exactly tells you wants wrong. your php version

Comment: how can I downgrade my php version to 7.2

Comment: I am using bitnami linux ec2 aws

Comment: php 7.2 only has 2 months of support left. are you sure that you want to downgrade?

Comment: what magento verison are you using?

Comment: php 7.3.20 apache 2

Comment: So what should be done now? I have php version 7.3

Comment: what magento version are you using

Comment: magento v:2.3.2 community

Comment: you should update your magento. 2.3.2 does not support php 7.3

Comment: i suggest updating to 2.3.5-p2

Comment: How Is it possible to update my magento version through cli

Comment: Is there any command for it?

Comment: Because I also have my whole store completely build on it.

Comment: updating magento can be quite tricky depending on how heavly your system is modified.
but working with updated versions is just shit.

the update process itself is quite easy and documented in the magento devdocs.

Comment: https://github.com/AmpersandHQ/ampersand-magento2-upgrade-patch-helper will help you a lot ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your php version is 7.3.20 and required version is 7.2.0

Downgrade your php version to 7.2 run the following commands :-

1. clear
2. sudo apt update
3. sudo apt purge php*
4. sudo apt autoremove
5. sudo apt autoclean
6. clear
7. sudo apt-get install -y php7.2 php7.2-mysql php7.2-bcmath php7.2-gd php7.2-bz2 php7.2-xml php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-intl php7.2-curl php7.2-json php7.2-zip php7.2-mbstring php7.2-soap